# Mix Java 5.0 and Java 6.0 Code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version, java-6, java-5

I have one module developed under java 5.0

```
package mypack;

class MessageParser {
    public MessageParser(String s) {
    ......
    }
}
```

I have another module developed under java 6.0

```
import mypack;
......
String str = someString;
MessageParser parser = new MessageParser(str);
......
```

But I　got the error
"cannot find symbol constructor MessageParser(java.lang.String)"

BTW: the IDE I am using is intellij idea

Could anyone tell me why and how to get it work?

Comment: Is the java 5 code only available as a jar/class file, or can you recompile it under java 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has little to do with Java5-6.

Probably you have a different version in your classpath.

Double check what jar/file you're using in your Java 6 code, and triple check it correspond to the one you're seeing in you Java 5 version. Mostlikely you're seeing an old version which didn't have the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has nothing to to with java version, but I think you're are trying to compile second class agains a old version of first class, which does not contain the constructor with one string arg.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the Java version, but with the way you're trying to connect your "modules" - how are these defined? As JAR files? Are you using an IDE?

Well, first of all, `import mypack;` will not import any classes in `mypack`. You either have to list the class as well or use a wildcard:

```
import mypack.MessageParser;
```

or

```
import mypack.*;
```